# Vue3, VeeValidate and Yup, how to validate fields

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, vee-validate, nuxt3

I'm having a bit of issues with making it validate fields in my form. I'm in a Nuxt3 project...

I've tried following the VeeValidate docs, but haven't been able to make it work correctly. All of their examples are using their own "Field" component, however, I'm using Vue Prime and their form components, so I can't make use of the Field component from VeeValidate - How can I make the form do validation? It should be on submit and also have "live validation", meaning the if you are in a fill and "blur" out, it should also show an error message:

The code I have is:

```
<template>
  <VForm @submit="handleAddUser" v-slot="{ values }">
    <FormItem :show-separator="false">
      <NuntioColorPicker @active-color="setUserColor" />
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem :show-separator="false" label="Display name">
      <InputText name="displayName" v-model="user.displayName" type="text" placeholder="Display name" />
      {{ errors.displayName }}
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem :show-separator="false" label="First name">
      <InputText v-model="user.firstName" type="text" placeholder="First name" />
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem :show-separator="false" label="Last name">
      <InputText v-model="user.lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last name" />
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem :show-separator="false" label="Email">
      <InputText v-model="user.email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem :show-separator="false" label="Phone">
      <InputText v-model="user.phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" />
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem :show-separator="false" label="Password">
      <InputText v-model="user.password" type="text" placeholder="Password" />
    </FormItem>
    <pre>{{ values }}</pre>
    <ModalActions>
      <NuntioButton ghost>Cancel</NuntioButton>
      <NuntioButton type="primary" @click="handleAddUser">Add user</NuntioButton>
      <button type="submit" @click="handleAddUser">SUbmit</button>
    </ModalActions>
  </VForm>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import FormItem from '~/components/atoms/FormItem/FormItem.vue';
import NuntioColorPicker from '~/components/molecules/NuntioColorPicker.vue';
import InputText from 'primevue/inputtext';
import ModalActions from '~/components/organisms/Modal/ModalActions.vue';
import NuntioButton from '~/components/atoms/Button/NuntioButton.vue';
import { useForm, Form as VForm } from 'vee-validate';
import * as yup from 'yup';

//TODO: Typings
const user = reactive({
  color: undefined,
  displayName: undefined,
  firstName: undefined,
  lastName: undefined,
  email: undefined,
  password: undefined,
  phone: undefined
});

const userSchema = yup
  .object({
    displayName: yup.string().required(),
    firstName: yup.string().required(),
    lastName: yup.string().required(),
    email: yup.string().email().required(),
    password: yup.string().required().min(6),
    phone: yup.string().required()
  })
  .required();

const { validate, errors } = useForm({
  validationSchema: userSchema,
  initialValues: user
});

const setUserColor = (color: string) => {
  user.color = color;
};

const handleAddUser = (values) => {
  console.log('values', values);
  console.log('errors', errors.value);
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't have an export default for your page that holds your methods and data?

In any case.
I had a similar issue with vue validation but I didn't use veelidate. Maybe my solution might work for you.

Change your v-form tag to

```
  <v-form @submit.prevent="handleAddUser" v-model='isValid' v-slot="{ values }">
```

data to hold your model and method that handles the add user

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
        isValid: false,
  }),
  methods: {
    handleAddUser = (values) => {
      if (isValid) {
         console.log('values', values);
         console.log('errors', errors.value);
      }
    };
  },
};
```

Then your buttons don't need @click events if they're type submit.

```
<NuntioButton type="submit">Add user</NuntioButton>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: The reason for no default export etc, is because im using Nuxt3 and the composition api... However, doing the above doesnt't do any difference unfortunately :/

Comment: only seeing this now, could you try v-form instead of VForm. mine is a v-form